# how to sorting dojo/multiselect list

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a two MultiSelect lists, can the left list be sorted after I move any value from right list to left?

```
button= new Button({
    label: "move left",
    onClick: lang.hitch(this, function(){
    dijit.byId(leftListId).addSelected(dijit.byId(rightListId));
})
```

Comment: The widgets from the dojo toolkit provide a lot of event handlers, for the user to override. Check http://dojotoolkit.org/api/ to see what events can you detect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly. The `MultiSelect` is one of the simplest widgets I think and is just a wrapper.
This means that there are no special features included and if you want to have a sort functionality you will have to make one by yourself.

The best way of making one by yourself is by extending the widget. An example:

```
declare("dijit/form/MultiSelect", [MultiSelect], {
    sort: function() {
        var domNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.containerNode.children);
        domNodes.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a.innerHTML < b.innerHTML) {
                return -1;
            } else if (a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML) {
                 return 0;   
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        });
        this.containerNode.innerHTML = "";
        array.forEach(domNodes, function(node) {
           this.containerNode.appendChild(node); 
        }, this);
    }
});
```

What this does is pretty easy. We add a function called `sort()` and then we just retrieve a list of all children, sort these children with the `sort()` function of an array and then we remove all children and add the sorted children.

To use it you can now do something like: `dijit.byId(leftListId).sort()` right after you executed your `addSelected()`.

An example JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XHk9b/1/).

Comment: var domNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.containerNode.children);
is showing jscript object expected error in IE but working perfectly for Firefox... any help???